# rspec failing - "Couldn't find table", but rake db:test:prepare doesn't fix it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, rake

I've been doing a major refactor that required several migrations.  All of a sudden, rspec is failing.

```
Could not find table 'users' (ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid)
```

The `users` table is right there in schema.rb:

```
  create_table "users", :primary_key => "user_id", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "first_name",          :limit => 100,                                    :null => false
    t.string   "last_name",           :limit => 100,                                    :null => false
    (...)
    t.boolean  "current_student",                    :default => true,                  :null => false
    t.boolean  "unregistered",                       :default => false,                 :null => false
  end
```

Here's what I've tried:

- `rake db:test:prepare`: No change
- removing `schema.rb` and recreating it with `rake db:schema:dump`: No change

My app is working fine - I can create users, log in, log out, etcetera.  But none of my tests work.  What should I try next?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue.

In one of my models, I had a scope written thus:

```
scope :registered, where(:registered => true)
```

Deep in the stack trace, there was actually a reference to this line.  I changed the scope to:

```
scope :registered, :conditions => {:registered => true}
```

...and everything worked.  Whew.

Answer (score 4):

Run `rake db:test:load` instead to create the test database from the `schema.rb` file

> The rake db:test:load recreates the test database from the current db/schema.rb. On subsequent attempts, it is a good idea to first run db:test:prepare, as it first checks for pending migrations and warns you appropriately.

More info: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#preparing-your-application-for-testing

Comment: Thanks, tried that and it didn't work....turned out there was a scope that was offending. It wasn't triggering any errors in the app, just when I tried to run my specs.

Comment: Found the issue.

In one of my models, I had a scope written thus:

    scope :unregistered, where(:unregistered => true)


Deep in the stack trace, there was actually a reference to this line.  I changed the scope to:

    scope :unregistered, :conditions => {:unregistered => true}

...and everything worked.  Whew.

Comment: Glad you figured it out! Typically this would remedy a bad `rake db:test:prepare` run though so I'll leave this answer up in case anyone else stumbles upon this question in the future

Comment: This was the issue for me. Saved me lots of frustration!